# Navbar doesn't work properly on mobile device

Tags: html, navigation, uinavigationbar

Here is my  [Index.html](https://github.com/tia337/testBootstrap/blob/gh-pages/index.html)
The problem is that while I'm opening it with desktop browser (scale it to small size) navbar works. But when I open it with Android Chrome browser and push nav button it doesn't respond.
Here is link for my page [page](http://tia337.github.io/testBootstrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the Javascript Console ? You have an error :

```
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
```

Add JQuery.js before your bootstrap.js script tag !

Comment: Actually I have added jQuery. I have folder called js in my repo and it's all there.                                                                                                                       <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: And by the way, it's better to put all js in the bottom of the page.

Comment: Actually it all depends. You can use defer/async to reduce the drawback of having it a the head. Also, having everything loaded *after* the script that uses it can sometimes add a lot of overhead for checking if the ressources are loaded and such. 
Load scripts at the end of the page is not a rule of thub, more of a "when it makes sense AND is practical".